# scrolling to the bottom of the data grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

I am using a datagridview with button field. when I click the button of the button field it will automatically scroll to the top of the datagridview's list. I have to scroll down again and again to click the buttons at the bottom of the list. Any solution?

Comment: datagridview is windows forms; gridview is webforms. Please clarify the technology you're using, adjust the question wording and remove inappropriate tags

Comment: its datagridview

Comment: Canm you post a code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is happening when the user clicks a button? If the code in the button click event changes the grids data source, then the grid will obviously reset to display the first record in the first row. You should elaborate or include what the code in the button click is doing in relation to the grid. It sounds like you may need to capture which row is the `FirstDisplayedCell`. However this is a guess since it is not clear what the button click code is doing.